# Listening for Facebook token update in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm currently using Facebook iOS SDK 3.1.1 without native integration.

How can I detect there is a change in the token or expiration extended but same token, without having to explicitly check after each FB action against a local NSUserDefaults copy?

I can't find much documentation for the NSNotificationCenter method names or the KVO usage in the SDK.